# C# - Dynamically Loaded Assembly Access To Parent Assembly References

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am trying to implement a plug-in style architecture.  There are core, external libraries used by both the plug-ins, and in the main application.  A good example of such library is JSON.NET.

As I develop plug-ins, I make reference to the same JSON.NET version referenced in the main application.  When the plug-in is compiled, I have not been merging the external libraries with the plug-in, as I expected the references to resolve to the same assemblies loaded by the main application.

However, this isn't working.  When I try to invoke methods of the plug-in in the main application, I am getting "could not load assembly..." error.

How to go about making the dynamically loaded plugins resolve references the main application's references?

Comment: Never use Assembly.LoadFile()

Comment: Assembly.LoadFrom(path)....Assuming your MainApp is referencing a assembly with "common" types that the plug-in needs to implement...

Answer (score 0):

A few considerations:

- Design your architecture in a way that you don't need the internal references from the core system. At Example you could create wrapper for the needed functions in the core which can be used in the plugins.
- in case of .NET 4.0+: unsing the dynamic keyword
- using Reflection
- Runtimecompiling